# Converting OpenCV Python code to OpenCV C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, opencv, numpy

I was trying to translate this OpenCV/Numpy Python code to C++ with OpenCV, but I have a few issues as I'm really new to Python.

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/deconvolution.py) and performs a Wiener deconvolution. Anyway, here are these few lines:

```
psf /= psf.sum()
psf_pad = np.zeros_like(img)
kh, kw = psf.shape
psf_pad[:kh, :kw] = psf #1
PSF = cv2.dft(psf_pad, flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT, nonzeroRows = kh)
PSF2 = (PSF**2).sum(-1) #2
iPSF = PSF / (PSF2 + noise)[...,np.newaxis] #3
RES = cv2.mulSpectrums(IMG, iPSF, 0)
res = cv2.idft(RES, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE | cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT )
```

`psf` and  `psf_pad` are numpy arrays.

I've noted the lines I don't understand with a `#number`.

Here's what I think those lines are doing:

Line #1: `psf_pad[:kh, :kw] = psf`:

This line seems to fill in the beginning of `psf_pad` with the `psf` 2D array.

Line #2: `PSF2 = (PSF**2).sum(-1)`:

From what I read, the `sum` function with a `-1` parameter is the row-sum of a matrix on which it's called.
So I guess the OpenCV equivalent must be the [`cv::reduce(...)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) function.

Line #3: `iPSF = PSF / (PSF2 + noise)[...,np.newaxis]` :

This one I really don't understand, it seems it reshapes the array. But in what way, that I don't really understand.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The last one seems to be `broadcasting`, which I am not sure if OpenCV C++ supports.

Comment: The last one is enclosing each individual element into an additional pair of square brackets, turning it into its own mini-array.

Comment: Oh, OK I see, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there an equivalent function in C++ using OpenCV or maybe some other lib ?